# How to Change Value of String From Null to Something New

Tags: c#

I have been doing my homework for the last few hours. However, I got stuck.

So basically I am trying to assign new value to a string in a Method. This new value must be passed to the method. I tried the following but the test failed.
(Please See attached screenshot)

Thank you very much in advance
[image]

```
private string surname;

private string ChangeSurname(ref string surname)
{
    this.surname = "New Value";
    return surname;
}
```

Note I tried without ref too but it did not solve the problem. Getting the same error message.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: ChangeSurname takes a reference now, while the task is to pass a value. Also show us the code that calls ChangeSurname. Add your improved code below the code you already posted, so we can see your progress.

Comment: `this.surname = surname; return surname;` - we change and then return; however, we do't want `ref` here

Comment: These answers won't be useful if you don't understand what [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) and [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) do. As you continue learning the language, make sure you know how those features work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need pass the argument as reference
2. As you are setting the global value in a private method, the method can be void and not return anything (of course there is no harm in returning it):

   ```
   private string surname;

   private void ChangeSurname(string newValue)
   {
       this.surname = newValue;
   }
   ```

or if you need to also return it after setting the value (which I doubt that):

```
private string ChangeSurname(string newValue)
{
    this.surname = newValue;
    return newValue;
}
```

Comment: This can be improved further by using const in the argument.

Comment: @BentTranberg I don't think so, it says the value should be passed as argument, the value is not actually `const` but the code in the question must be misleading

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Mr. Ashkan. I tried both solution. However, I am still getting the same exact error message.

Comment: Using const in the argument is normal to indicate that the argument will not be changed in the method. This again improves readability and produces more efficient executable code.

Comment: @BentTranberg I'm confused where the `const` keyword should be added.

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful but VS is also returning these two messages in the Error List: 
1) Message S1144: Remove the unused private method 'ChangeSurname'. ClassesAndObjectsTask
2) IDE0051 Private member 'Employee.ChangeSurname' is unused ClassesAndObjectsTask

Comment: So am I. Looks like I've made a mistake here. Sorry about that. In other languages const is used before string in the argument. From what I can see now after experimenting, not in C#. I'm no longer programming C# on a daily basis, but was used to const from Delphi and C-like languages.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Thank you it worked. I just had to change private access modifier to public.

Answer (score 0):

String is a reference type & it is immutable. When a reference type variable is passed from one method to another, it doesn't create a new copy; instead, it passes the variable's address. So, If we change the value of a variable in a method, it will also be reflected in the calling method.

```
public class Name{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public void ChangeSurname(Name name2,string NewVal)
{
    name2.Surname   = NewVal;
}
```

Now the method ChangeSurname() can be called like as below

```
    Name name1 = new Name();        
    name1.Surname = "Tiwary";
    ChangeSurname(name1,"Sharma");
```

Output: Surname "Tiwary" will be changed to "Sharma"